# SonarQube Visual Studio Bootstrapper can't finding assemblies

Tags: configuration, installation, sonarqube, sonar-runner

we are using sonar for analysing C# solutions. We need to use the REST API of sonar so we update it to the 4.3 version. Now we see that the .NET Ecosystem has change and following the [Upgrade from the .NET Ecosystem](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Upgrade+from+the+.NET+Ecosystem) shows how now works the runner with .NET projects. I activated the Visual Studio Bootstrapper because I was getting this error:

```
ERROR: Caused by: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set.
```

but when I run again the runner I still got that error and looking in the log I found this lines for the projects of the solution

```
16:02:27.280 INFO  - Locating the assembly for the project: XXX...
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\Debug_AnyCPU\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 WARN  - The properties "sonar.dotnet.buildConfiguration" and "sonar.dotnet.buildPlatform" are deprecated
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was found, but rejected because it does not match the request build configuration and platform: <somepath>\Release_AnyCPU\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\DebugExpress_AnyCPU\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\ReleaseExpress_AnyCPU\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\Debug_x64\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 WARN  - The properties "sonar.dotnet.buildConfiguration" and "sonar.dotnet.buildPlatform" are deprecated
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was found, but rejected because it does not match the request build configuration and platform: <somepath>\Release_x64\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\DebugExpress_x64\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\ReleaseExpress_x64\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\Debug_x86\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\Release_x86\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\DebugExpress_x86\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built: <somepath>\ReleaseExpress_x86\XXX.dll
16:02:27.280 WARN  - Unable to locate the assembly of project <somepath>\XXX\XXX.csproj
```

My configurations file are:

runner:

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
#----- Security (when 'sonar.forceAuthentication' is set to 'true')
sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\\
```

project:

```
# Project identification
sonar.projectKey=XX:XXX
sonar.projectVersion=1.1
sonar.projectName=XXX

# Info required for Sonar 
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=cs
#sonar.dotnet.key.generation.strategy=safe
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#sonar.dotnet.key.generation.strategy=safe

sonar.gendarme.mode=skip
sonar.ndeps.mode=skip
sonar.stylecop.mode=skip
```

I hope any can help me with this because I seems we can't still using sonar for our analysis and coverage process.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to solve your error in the end?
I was getting the same error and it got solved indeed by adding the *Analysis bootstrapper for Visual Studio projects* plugin to the Sonar server. 
My sonar project properties file contains only this fxcop information:

```
sonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\\
```

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, it seems that the Visual Studio Bootstrapper did manage to find some assembly candidates, but they did not match your requested build configuration and build platform.

Remove the values for `sonar.dotnet.buildConfiguration` and `sonar.dotnet.buildPlatform` in the SonarQube Settings page under "Settings > Visual Studio Bootstrapper > Deprecated".

Moreover, `sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath` should be set to the full path of FxCop, including the trailing "FxCopCmd.exe" part.